# Why is all-time reputation score different on the new Users page than it is at the top of the screen?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, users, reputation-leagues

I noticed that there is a 250 point disparity between my reputation as it appears at the top of my screen and as it appears on the User Leagues page.

Why?

Comment: What numbers do you see on what page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see 2946 on your user page and 2,690 in the league.  I believe the issue is that the league data is not refreshed instantly. Check it in again later and it should catch up.

Comment: Yup, the league updates a little after 0:00 UTC.  /users is a live number.

Comment: I wondered about that, but the OP saying *new* Users page made me think /users.

Comment: @Hans: thanks for that, i was looking when it got updated but it isn't wrote anywhere